# spring-boot multi threading aggregation and vice versa

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, parallel-processing, executorservice

We are building spring-boot application. At present Rest controller is calling multiple webservices in sequential manner. Now we need to perform these calls in parallel and return response as per below condition

1. Aggregate - Wait for all parallel webservices call to complete and then aggregate response and return the same.
2. No Aggregation - Return response whichever webservice call is completed first and abandon/cancel/interrupt rest of in progress call.

I have done some research and found ExecutorService but not sure if this will fit into both type of scenarios as I am very new to Spring-Boot.

Please let me know if there is way to achieve the same.

Comment: You could implement it yourself, which is fun; but there are frameworks that can help you with that, for example https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix or https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava

Comment: Nice suggestions !!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, `ExecutorService` is a good idea and you should submit a `Callable` to `ExecutoService` so that you get back a `Future`.

To handle situation # 1 , you should logically AND return value of [isDone()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isDone()) method call for all Futures and to handle situation # 2, you should do logical OR and something like that.

Here are references - [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) & [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

I am not suggesting specific to Spring Boot but coming from Core Java back ground. This will get you started then you can refine approaches and switch APIs.

Hope it helps !!